# How do I update a hidden field in jquery for dynamically created rows in a table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

I am using a partial view and JQuery to dynamically add rows to a table.

Basically very similar to [MVC 5 BeginCollectionItem with Partial CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774822/mvc-5-begincollectionitem-with-partial-crud)

I have a Total column that is simply the price * qty.

another cell is using @Html.TextBoxFor to enter a discount percent.

```
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PercentDiscount, new {@class = "form-control discount", type = "number"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PercentDiscount)
</td>
```

I then recalculate the total cell using JQuery and click a Save button to POST the data to an Action.

The problem I have is the edited Total does not post correctly, it becomes 0, while the rest of the data POSTS just fine.

If I don't change the discount value, the Total from the model returned from the PartialViewResult Action POSTS correctly.

I'm not sure if I have to set the hidden value again in JQuery or how I should do it.

Below is the JQuery to edit the Total:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".discount").on("change", function() {
        var discountValue = $(this).closest('input');

        var price = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text();
        var qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(6)').text();
        var discount = ((price * qty) * discountValue / 100);
        var total = (price * qty) - discount;

        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(8)').html(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: If you need calcualtion to get posted then it would need to be set in an input's value. The html itself doesn't get submitted

Comment: Isn't it perhaps possible to update the item in the collection?

Comment: What *"collection"* or *"item"* are you referring to?

Comment: The BeginCollectionItem collection.

Comment: I don't use MVC and that only exists on server. If you submit a form...the form must contain all the data needed. And it sounds like you are submitting a form

Comment: The @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PercentDiscount)'s value is POSTED even if I change the value, so how can I POST another cell's value when changed?

Comment: either need another field....or post by ajax or do calcs on server